# Spark 3.4.1 - speculation results in failure - commitDeniedError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming to read & process & write data from and into Kafka.

Spark Version: 3.4.1
Kafka Version: 3.3.2
Yarn Version: 3.2.1
Hadoop Version: 3.2.3

Below is the exception information and I don't know why this happened.

```
2023-06-28 17:37:29  INFO Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) utils.AppInfoParser:119 - Kafka version: 3.3.2
2023-06-28 17:37:29  INFO Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) utils.AppInfoParser:120 - Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
2023-06-28 17:37:29  INFO Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) utils.AppInfoParser:121 - Kafka startTimeMs: 1687945049829
2023-06-28 17:37:29  INFO kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1 clients.Metadata:287 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: B1tTZYkQQGOwfo3mBR8sBg
2023-06-28 17:37:30  INFO Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) v2.DataWritingSparkTask:60 - Commit denied for partition 87 (task 68312, attempt 7, stage 329.0).
2023-06-28 17:37:30 ERROR Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) util.Utils:97 - Aborting task
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Commit denied for partition 87 (task 68312, attempt 7, stage 329.0).
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.commitDeniedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1563)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-06-28 17:37:30 ERROR Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) v2.DataWritingSparkTask:76 - Aborting commit for partition 87 (task 68312, attempt 7, stage 329.0)
2023-06-28 17:37:30 ERROR Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) v2.DataWritingSparkTask:76 - Aborted commit for partition 87 (task 68312, attempt 7, stage 329.0)
2023-06-28 17:37:30 ERROR Executor task launch worker for task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312) executor.Executor:97 - Exception in task 87.7 in stage 329.0 (TID 68312)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Commit denied for partition 87 (task 68312, attempt 7, stage 329.0).
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.commitDeniedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1563)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried config speculation parameters like below:

```
spark.speculation true
spark.speculation.efficiency.enabled true
spark.speculation.multiplier 2
spark.speculation.minTaskRuntime 1000ms
spark.speculation.interval 1000ms
spark.speculation.quantile 0.9
```

but it didn't help.

If I set spark.speculation to false then this error will not happen.